# How to check if node existst in the XML or not?

Tags: php, xml, laravel

I am using this code to parse the XML response from the API. Getting the error Trying to get property of non-object

```
$doc = new  \DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($response);
$doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$doc->formatOutput = true;
$xml_string = $doc->saveXML();
$doc->loadXML($xml_string);
```

it is working fine if it gives the correct result but if it gives a error it gives error call to undefined object. I am accessing the values like this

```
if($doc->getElementsByTagName('accepted')->item(0)->nodeValue == true){
    $json = array(
        'success' => 1,
        'ACN' => $doc->getElementsByTagName('acn')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'URL' => htmlspecialchars($doc->getElementsByTagName('certificateUrl')->item(0)->nodeValue)
    );

}else{
    $json = array(
        'success' => 0,
        'error' =>"",
    );
}
```

So if the value of accepted is true it works fine and gives the desired result. But if accepted not exists it throws the error. How I can check that the node exists or not in the XML ? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DOM::getElementsByTagName](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) returns a [DOMNodeList](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php) instance. This object has a length property that you can check before going on to access items in it.

```php
$acceptedItems = $doc->getElementsByTagName('accepted');
if ($acceptedItems->length > 0 && $acceptedItems->item(0)->nodeValue === 'true') {
    $json = array(
        'success' => 1,
        'ACN' => $doc->getElementsByTagName('acn')->item(0)->nodeValue,
        'URL' => htmlspecialchars($doc->getElementsByTagName('certificateUrl')->item(0)->nodeValue)
    );
} else {
    $json = array(
        'success' => 0,
        'error' => "",
    );
}
```